# What monitoring tools are available to monitor the load testing being done by IBM rational performance tester?

Tags: testing, performance-testing, load-testing, rpt, rational-performance-test

I am doing the load testing by using IBM rational performance tester on an application. I want to monitor the various resources like servers, middleware, networking etc. during the load testing in order to pinpoint the bottleneck. What monitoring tools I can use with IBM rational performance tester?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PerfMon utility for tracking many hardware resources. in schedule, go to resource monitoring category and Enable Resource monitoring. It will give you Min, Max and Average value for a given time. alternatively you can also start perfmon on server which will give you entire details for each time  interval you have set.

Comment: I use perfmon when running LoadRunner, but LoadRunner comes with an extensive and integrated set of network and backend server monitoring tools. What do people use with RPF?